# Galaxy S2 screen is black, but touch-screen still functional.

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, touchscreen

No idea what happened, last night it was working till it ran out of battery and turned off. Woke up this morning and kind of rolled over on it with my elbow, no big deal it seemed like though. A little while later after I charged it the phone would turn on, make the sound etc but nothing on the screen, I can still feel the vibration when I try to move an icon for example. And it the computer still recognized it when plugged in, any solutions? Or am I outta luck?

Comment: Did it crack when you rolled over it? Try taking out the battery for a few minutes, put it back in. See if that helps? If not, I suggest you take it to a service center.

Comment: Nope, and your solution didn't work. Guess I'll have to get it fixed, thanks for the help anyways :(

Comment: Coming from an off state, can you go into download mode (volume down + home + power combo) or recovery mode (volume up + home + power combo)?

Comment: @geffchang No unfortuantely not, nothing appears on-screen. Damn it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, this looks like a hardware issue, and not a software/Android issue. I would suggest sending it to a service center for repair.